# How do you set the specific url path you want to work with in cxf?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf, jax-rs

I am using the annotated methods in CXF to create different functionality through web service calls. For some reason, all of my URL paths come off of `{hostname}/services/status/{my_path}`. I am using annoted methods like so:

```
    @Path("/{type:(?i)index}")
    public IndexServiceResource getIndexServiceResource() {
        return new IndexServiceResource(this.handlers);
    }
```

I would like for the `@Path` to come straight off of the `{hostname}` instead of `{hostname}/services/status`. Where would this be set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind CXFServlet "/services" which handles cxf web-services to main context "/" in your web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
   <display-name>cxf</display-name>
   <description>cxf</description>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Try to change url-pattern from "/services/*" to "/*".

However I'm not sure is there any way to change "/status" to be also bind to main context "/*".

Of course if your request are passing through Apache proxy then it is a possible to set mapping for example "http://my.domain" -> "http://internal.server/services/status". But this is done outside your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "status" is required due to your Jaxrs server configuration (Through i am not sure). Please check your jaxrs server configuration in your context file.

```
<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
```

Does the address property contains status ?